# Access session in Global class

Tags: playframework-2.0

I intensely need my user object so I thought I would store it in the Cache. Since I do not know when it is destroyed from the Cache, I though to put it as an `interceptor`. So I defined the following code:

```
@Override
public Action<?> onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
    // find the user based on the userId that is stored in the session
    // scope.
    String userId = session.get("user"); // does not work
    User loggedInUser = (User) Cache.get(userId);
    if (loggedInUser == null) {
        loggedInUser = User.getUerById(userSyscode);
    }
    return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
}
```

I thought that I can use:

```
session.get("user");
```

But it seems to me, like the `session` is not accessible from the `Global class`, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it with "action composition".
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaActionsComposition

Alternatively, this is the code for `onRequest` that you are overriding, so I would think you can do the same thing and just put your code in the `call` method.

```
public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
  return new Action.Simple() {
    public Result call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {

      /* your code here */

      return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
  };
}
```

I don't know if `session` will be available directly, but at that point you can get to it from the `ctx` variable. I think it'll be something like `ctx.session().get("user")`.

Answer (score 0):

In scala works this code:

```
override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    if(!request.session.get("email").isEmpty){
        //I have session with email
        request.session.apply("email") //this is for getting session
    }
}
```

request.session.get return Option[String]

request.session.apply return String

[play framework 2 scala Play.api.mvc.Session](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Session)