# play framework(v2.3) onRouteRequest session

Tags: session-cookies, global, playframework-2.1

Hi all i am new play framework and i am not good at english
So please understand me.

My Question is how to get session infomation in `Global.onRouteRequest`

```
public play.api.mvc.Handler onRouteRequest(RequestHeader request) {

// how to i access session here?

// request.session <- not working

// Http.Context.current().session().get(COOKIE_VALUE) <- not working

}
```

My aim is login and store infomation in session and return session key to client
and I would like to check all session in `onRouteRequest` by cookie

Comment: Override ``onRequest`` instead of ``onRouteRequest``. Also, check out this answer for [accessing the session when extending GlobalSettings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10712629/926710).

Answer (score 0):

```
override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {

  routes(request)
}

def routes(request: RequestHeader) ={
(request.method, request.path) match {
  case ("GET", "/" ) => Some(controllers.Application.index)

  case("POST", "/login") => Some(Action.async(parse.json) {
    request => {

      val userId = request.session.get("userID")
      //ur logics
      Future(Ok(Json.toJson(userId)))
    }
  })
  case _ => None
}
}
```

Hope it works 4 u